# Parse date timestamp in SQL filename using RegEx

Tags: regex, bash, parsing

I am building a bash script for backing up databases. I've already set up a cron job to running this script daily and I already can dump the .sql files according to the following format:

```
YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS-databasename.sql
```

Considering the timestamp formatted name, I want to build another bash script that will parse the `YYMMDD` filename part and select all the daily files of the last week. This new bash script will run weekly.

How can I parse these numbers into a date using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting the date part from a filename with RegEx:

```
^(20[12]\d)(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])_\d+-\w+\.sql$
```

Explained regex here: http://regex101.com/r/iU7wL5

**Update** *with correct time validation also*:

```
^(20[12]\d)(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])_([01]\d|2[0-3])[0-5]\d[0-5]\d-\w+\.sql$
```

Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/yV1dD7

Note: this works on dates in 2010-2029 range and validates the filename to your output format

Answer (score 2):

Here a complete solution, try doing this :

without *regex* but *offset cut* (assuming your example is the same format for all files , like a script does when running in `crontab`):

```
cd /path/to/dumps
str='20130321_145907-databasename.sql'
for i in {7..14}; do
    curfile=$(date -d ${str:0:8} -d "$i days ago" '+%Y%m%d')*
    if [[ -s $curfile ]]; then
        # do something with "$curfile"
    fi
done
```

If you really need a **regex** :

```
cd /path/to/dumps
str='20130321_145907-databasename.sql'
if [[ $str =~ ^([0-9]{8})_[0-9]{6} ]]; then
    for i in {7..14}; do
        curfile=$(date -d ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -d "$i days ago" '+%Y%m%d')*
        if [[ -s $curfile ]]; then
            # do something with "$curfile"
        fi
    done
fi
```

### Note

- note the final glob `*` on the `curfile=` line

Answer (score 1):

With bash 3+:

```
$ file=20130321_foo.log
$ [[ $file =~ ^[0-9]{8} ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
20130321
$
```

Comment: He wants to select daily files, this wont help that much. Try to complete it please

Comment: The OP's question is *"How can I parse these numbers into a date using regex?"* And sounds like he knows how to do his remaining work when he knows how to get the yyyymmdd part. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
LAST_WEEK_BEG=$(date --date="-7 days" +%Y%m%d)
LAST_WEEK_END=$(date --date="-14 days" +%Y%m%d)


if [ $YOUR_DATE -ge "$LAST_WEEK_BEG" ] && [ $YOUR_DATE -le "$LAST_WEEK_END" ]; then
   do things
fi
```

Comment: Complete it with KlarKW answer ;)

Comment: -1 for parsing `ls`.  `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @fedorqui : Did you see [my answer ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15549549/465183)

Comment: Of course I did, @sputnick and like it. Anyway, what's so bad about parsing `ls`? OK now I see you updated your first comment.

Comment: It is an interesting article. As I do not want to copy from your post, I just rollback to my first answer in which I consider the limits of last week, so I think you could un-downvote, @sputnick. Good to know this issue about `ls`!